# fastavro - Convert json file into avro file

Tags: python, avro, fastavro

A bit new to avro & python.

I am trying to do a simple conversion to avro using the fastavro library, as the speed of the native apache avro library is just a bit too slow.

I want to:

1.Take a json file
2. Convert the data to avro.

My problem is that it seems like my json isn't in the correct 'record' format to be converted to avro. I even tried putting my json into a string var and making it looks similar to the syntax they have on the site @ https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writer.html:

```
    {u'station': u'011990-99999', u'temp': 22, u'time': 1433270389},
    {u'station': u'011990-99999', u'temp': -11, u'time': 1433273379},
    {u'station': u'012650-99999', u'temp': 111, u'time': 1433275478},
```

Here is my code:

```
from fastavro import json_writer, parse_schema, writer
import json

key = "test.json"
schemaFileName = "test_schema.avsc"
with open(r'C:/Path/to/file' + schemaFileName) as sc:
    w = json.load(sc)

schema = parse_schema(w)

with open(r'C:/Path/to/file/' + key) as js:
    x=json.load(js)

with open('C:/Path/to/file/output.avro', 'wb') as out:
    writer(out, schema,x, codec='deflate')
```

Here is what I get as output:

```
  File "avropython.py", line 26, in <module>
    writer(out, schema,x, codec='deflate')
  File "fastavro\_write.pyx", line 608, in fastavro._write.writer
ValueError: "records" argument should be an iterable, not dict
```

My json file and schema, rspectively:

```
  "joined": false,
  "toward": {
    "selection": "dress",
    "near": true,
    "shoulder": false,
    "fine": -109780201.3804388,
    "pet": {
      "stood": "saddle",
      "live": false,
      "leather": false,
      "tube": false,
      "over": false,
      "impossible": true
    },
    "higher": false
  },
  "wear": true,
  "asleep": "door",
  "connected": true,
  "stairs": -1195512399.5000324
}
```

```
{
  "name": "MyClass",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "joined",
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    {
      "name": "toward",
      "type": {
        "name": "toward",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "selection",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "near",
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          {
            "name": "shoulder",
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          {
            "name": "fine",
            "type": "float"
          },
          {
            "name": "pet",
            "type": {
              "name": "pet",
              "type": "record",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "stood",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "name": "live",
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                {
                  "name": "leather",
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                {
                  "name": "tube",
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                {
                  "name": "over",
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                {
                  "name": "impossible",
                  "type": "boolean"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "higher",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "wear",
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    {
      "name": "asleep",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "connected",
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    {
      "name": "stairs",
      "type": "float"
    }
  ]
}
```

If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error `ValueError: "records" argument should be an iterable, not dict`, the problem is that when you call `writer`, the argument for the records needs to be an iterable. One way to solve this is to change your last line to `writer(out, schema, [x], codec='deflate')`

Alternatively, there is a `schemaless_writer` that can be used to just write a single record: https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writer.html#fastavro._write_py.schemaless_writer